# Custom element in Polymer.dart not showing

Tags: html, dart, dart-polymer, polymer-1.0

Since I seem to keep having issues with [disappearing elements in Polymer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33510122/only-first-local-dom-element-showing-with-polymer)...

I have the following files:

`pubspec.yaml`:

```python
name: photon
dependencies:
  polymer:
    git:
      url: git://github.com/dart-lang/polymer-dart.git
      ref: 1.0.0-rc.5
  polymer_elements:
    git:
      url: git://github.com/dart-lang/polymer_elements.git
  web_components: ^0.12.0
  reflectable: ^0.3.0
transformers:
- web_components:
    entry_points:
      - web/index.html
- reflectable:
    entry_points:
      - web/index.dart
```

`web/index.html`:

```html
<head>
  <link rel="import" href="packages/polymer/polymer.html">
  <link rel="import" href="packages/polymer_elements/paper_toolbar.html">
  <link rel="import" href="photo_view.html">
</head>
<body>
  <paper-toolbar>
    <div class="title">Photon</div>
  </paper-toolbar>
  <photo-view url="abc123"></photo-view>
  <script type="application/dart" src="index.dart"></script>
</body>
```

`web/index.dart`:

```dart
export 'package:polymer/init.dart';
```

`web/photo_view.html`:

```html
<dom-module id="photo-view">
  <template>
    <p>Photo <span>{{url}}</span> goes here with filters
    [<span>{{filters}}</span>]</p>
  </template>
</dom-module>
```

`web/photo_view.dart`:

```dart
@HtmlImport('photo_view.html')
library photon.photo_view;

import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';
import 'package:web_components/web_components.dart' show HtmlImport;

@PolymerRegister('photo-view')
class PhotoView extends PolymerElement {
  PhotoView.created() : super.created();

  @Property(notify: true)
  String url;
}
```

Based on the documentation I have found for Polymer.dart 1.0, this *should* work. Only issue is, the `photo-view` simply doesn't appear. At all. All I see is the toolbar. Unlike the last time this happened, rearranging the elements in `index.html` doesn't do a thing. I have tried:

- Importing `photo_elements.dart` from `index.dart`.
- Rearranging various imports and nodes in `index.html`.
- Explicitly adding `<script type="application/dart" src="photo_view.dart"></script>` to `photo_view.html`.

None of them do anything. I even tried deleting the `build` and `packages` directories and re-running `pub get` and `pub build`.

If I open up `build/web/index.html`, I can see that none of the registration code from `photo_view.dart` is added. In fact, *nothing* from `photo_view.dart` is present. Could this be part of the issue?

Answer (score 1):

I changed `index.dart` to

```
import 'photo_view.dart';
import 'package:polymer_elements/paper_toolbar.dart';
export 'package:polymer/init.dart';
/// Silence analyzer [PhotoView], [PaperToolbar]
const _silence = 0;
```

And it worked.
The last two lines are only to prevent "unused import hints" from the Dart analyzer.

Comment: So you're saying to remove those imports from `index.html` and add the Dart ones to `index.dart`? Unfortunately, that doesn't do anything helpful. `photo-view` is still invisible, and none of the code in `photo_view.dart` is in `build/web/index.html`..

Comment: I updated my answer. I switched completely away from `<link rel="import"` and haven't used it in Polymer 1.0.x at all. It should still work but I guess your component would need a `<script type="application/dart" src="photo_view.dart"></script>` to make it work.

Comment: Nope. Still doesn't work for me. Could it be an issue with my Dart2js or Pub version? Both are at `1.12.2`.

Comment: See https://github.com/bwu-dart-playground/polymer1/tree/master/so33530979_custom_element_not_showing for full working example. Dart version could be the cause. I'm on newest 1.13 You don't need Git dependencies anymore for Polymer 1.0.x but you need to add the `-` part for `pub get` not ignoring the release candidate versions (like `^1.0.0-rc.5`)

Comment: Ok; this *has* to be an issue with Dart. Your working code won't work for me, either. Definitely something outside of the code.

Comment: Try a Dart 1.13 developer release or wait a few days until 1.13 stable is released.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `<link rel="import">` style imports in your html (instead of dart imports in your dart file) then you will need to change your reflectable transformer configuration a bit:

```
- reflectable:
    entry_points:
      - web/index.bootstrap.initialize.dart
```

This is because the `index.dart` file can't reach the dart files which appear inside the html imports. The bootstrapped file however does contain all the necessary imports.

In general though it is encouraged to use dart imports instead of html imports.

Comment: Is there a particular benefit/loss from using Dart imports vs HTML ones?

Comment: Dart imports simplify life. You get analyser warnings for broken imports. You don't need to care about the correct number of `../../../somepackage/some_element.html`.